# Keras input shape ordering is (width, height, ch)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I use Keras2 with TensorFlow as back-end and tried feed horizontal rectangle image *(width:150 x height:100 x ch:3)* into network.

I use cv2 for pre-processing images and cv2 & TensorFlow treats the shape of images as [*height, width, ch*] ordering (*in my case, it's [100, 150, 3]* This format is opposite of *(width:150 x height:100 x ch:3)*, but it's not mistake.)

So I defined Keras model API input as follow code, but it occurred an error.

```python
img = cv2.imread('input/train/{}.jpg'.format(id))
img = cv2.resize(img, (100, 150))

inputs = Input(shape=(100, 150, 3))
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inputs)
~~~
```

error message is below

```python
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_4 to have shape
(None, 100, 150, 3) but got array with shape (4, 150, 100, 3)
```

By the way `input = Input((150, 100, 3))` can be run.

I feel weird with discrepancy between Keras & TensorFlow, so I'm suspicious that it just don't occurred error, it does not worked properly.

Anybody can explain that? I couldn't locate the input shape ordering in Keras Document.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the dimension ordering as you prefer. 
You can print and change the dimension ordering like this:

```python
from keras import backend as K
print(K.image_data_format()) # print current format
K.set_image_data_format('channels_last') # set format
```

If you want to permanently change the dimension ordering, you should edit it in the `keras.json` file, usually located at `~/.keras/keras.json`:

```python
"image_data_format": "channels_last"
```

Comment: I can resolve the problem since naive my misunderstands, but Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 4):

My problem occurred from order of width&height at argument of cv2.resize().
cv2.resize() takes the argument like `cv2.resize(img, (width, height))`, whereas numpy treats image array order of (height, width).

Answer (score 4):

Taken from https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/

> **Arguments**
>
> ...
>
> **data_format**: A string, one of channels_last (default) or
> channels_first. The ordering of the dimensions in the inputs.
> channels_last corresponds to inputs with shape (batch_size, height,
> width, channels) while channels_first corresponds to inputs with shape
> (batch_size, channels, height, width). It defaults to the
> image_data_format value found in your Keras config file at
> ~/.keras/keras.json. If you never set it, then it will be
> channels_last.
>
> ...

So it is: `(batch_size, height, width, channels)` (by default)